# add horizontal blank-grid rows to fill up the page in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

add horizontal blank-grid rows to fill up the page after the groups-total rows. Any insight on this would be very appreciated. I have read about using UNION. However I want to do changes in reporting end. Using Modulus function in visibility setting can be seems to solve. Then again, it can't be applied since I have group total rows after data row.
[image]
I want to add two more blank rows below the tablix in each page in order to maintain the same layout.

[image]
This is the grouping I am having currently in my report designer.

Comment: You need to be much clearer about several things before anyone can help you: (1) What exactly is your desired end result (not just what you think you need to do), (2) What have you tried thus far and what was the outcome?, and (3) any screenshots or visual aids that will help us understand what you need. Please EDIT your answer to include these things, rather than just replying in the comments.

Comment: I have added the screen shots that I want to achieve. Any insight on this matter? I have tried nested tablix but it looks quite messy and I function for Row Limiting is not working too.